# Cloud Run, Secret Manager file mount on volume and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, dockerfile, google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

I want to load whole application.properties file from GCP Secret Manager to my Spring Boot application while starting the application on cloud run
Secret is "mounted as volume" in Cloud Run (whole .properties file, in path /opt), but I not able to provide the correct path in CMD or Entrypoint in dockerfile for -Dspring.config.location="path-of-mounted-properties" and in cloud run deployment

I tried with CMD java -Xmx3g -jar app.jar -Dspring.config.location=/path/to/opt/application-properties. I had to use "-" in secret creation as "." is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

The -`Dspring.config.location` property should be specified before the `-jar` not after it. This is because any arguments that are passed after the `-jar` option are application arguments not JVM arguments.

Comment: CMD java -Xmx3g -Dspring.config.location=/path/to/opt/application-properties -jar app.jar is it correct ? and is the path specified correct i have mounted the properties file on /opt path in secret manager in cloud run

Comment: CMD java -Xmx3g -Dspring.config.location=file:/opt/application-properties -jar app.jar

Comment: file not found at the mounted path error